# An odd double word sentence, is it acceptable?

Tags: doubled-words

The sentence in question is:

> I detailed the projects I had a hand **in in** my journal.

I've got this lovely double in, in my sentence! Is this acceptable? I usually try to avoid the classic "had had".

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with saying that if only I'd had any idea this would get me executed at dawn, I'd never have written it with *had had*?

Answer (score 3):

Is it grammatical? Yes. This is a matter of style. Your sentence sounds a bit odd, however, but not for the reason you suggest. More about that later.

Note that it's not even bad style to repeat a word immediately if the sentence makes sense and is clear.

> "Honesty? He discovered that that was the best policy after all."

Nevertheless, style is a matter of personal preference. If the doubling in your own sentence bothers you, recast the sentence. For example,

> "I detailed in my journal the projects I had a hand in."

There's *always* a different way to say something. Find one that suits you.

Now, about the sentence as you gave it:

> "I detailed the projects I had a hand in in my journal."

That is a bit ambiguous, since the sentence could refer to detailing *in your journal* those projects, or detailing *only* those projects that appear in your journal. My suggestion above assumes the former, but if you mean the latter, recast to make that clearer.

Answer (score -1):

"have a hand in" is neither a formal collocation, nor a frequent colloquial one. It is understood, but it's not yet an univerbation *hand-in* (in contrast to e.g. *beat-down*). I think the proscriptive rule against dangling prepositions gains some merrit on account of such examples.

I can't give a syntactic analysis, but I would say "in which I had a hand" as a relative clause, it would work. At that, *in-which* (or *wherein*) would be a collocation you can't just drop. But that's obviously not what have on your mind. I'm not here to denigrate, I'm just agreeing that reduplication is hard on the eyes, if nothing else.